# Setting up batch if statements correctly

Tags: batch-file, timer, batch-processing

I've written a timer into a batch script so I can compare the real time execution of a file vs its internal run time which looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls

for /f "delims=_" %%J in ('forfiles /p "%%F" /m *.ext /c "cmd /c echo @path"') DO (
    set start=!time!
    echo Start Time: !start!
    start "PROGRAM" /D "C:Program Files\Path\to\PROGRAM"
    set end=!time!
    echo End Time: !end! 
    for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("!start!") do (
        set /a "start=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
    )       

for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("!end!") do (
        set /a "end=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
    )
set /A elapsed=end-start
if !elapsed! lss 0 set /a elapsed + 8640000 
echo Elapsed Time: !elapsed!
```

The second to last line `if` statement is there to solve the problem of the script running past midnight however, it doesn't seem to be working and I'll still get negative times. Can anyone spot an error here?

Additionally, I'd like to create another layer of error reporting so that even with the aforementioned line of code functioning *perfectly*, I'd like to add another layer of if that would set !elapsed! = null if its negative. Probably important to note that I'm still new to batch and learning all of this as I go.

Comment: One issue - Your `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` line is misspelled (an extra `d`)

Comment: fixed, and it was only misspelled here not in my script.

Answer (score 2):

Read `set /a` [command line reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754250.aspx) or this [great resource](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html). Therefore, your line could be as follows:

```
if !elapsed! lss 0 set /a "elapsed+=8640000"
```

or (giving the same result)

```
if !elapsed! lss 0 set /a "elapsed = elapsed + 8640000"
```

Comment: I can't see any _assignment_ operator in your `set /a elapsed + 8640000`. So although the `elapsed + 8640000` expression is evaluated, the result is not assigned...

Comment: Okay, so the `+=` is assigning the elapsed variable an additional 8640000?

Comment: if I add this line below: `if !elapsed! lss 0 set /a "elapsed="`, will that check after adding 8640000 if the elapsed variable is negative and then set it to null? I'm hoping that line will never actually kick off. Just some error control

Comment: `set /a "elapsed="` raises `Missing operand` error with `"%errorlevel%"=="1073750989"` keeping the `%elapsed%` variable unchanged

Comment: what about `set "elapsed="` and if the `/a` had nothing to do with it, how could I do this? Also, what is the data type of error levels?

Comment: Using `set "elapsed="` will erase the `%elapsed%` variable and could be tested using `if "%elapsed%"==""` or `if not exist elapsed` (gives `true` in both cases). Really, all environment variables are strings and  `if %errorlevel% equ 0` (numeric comparison) is  equivalent  to `if "%errorlevel%"=="0"` (string comparison)

Comment: So how could I write the equivalent of `if !errorlevel! != 0 set elapsed = null`

Comment: `if !errorlevel! NEQ 0` (http://ss64.com/nt/if.html). The `set "elapsed=null"` assigns **string** `null`. There is no _null_ value in the command line interpreter. Again: all data stored in environment variables are **strings**